# Can you explain "causing greyed out vision" grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

"Oxygen deprivation in the retinal cells impairs their ability to process light, causing greyed out vison"

I have a question of the sentence above.
I think "causing"is a verb and "greyed out"is also verb.
How is this sentence correct grammatically?

Comment: In this sentence "greyed out" is used as an adjective: **greyed out vision**.

Comment: Oxygen deprivation greys out  vision.  The vision becomes greyed out.  We call such vision **greyed out vision**. Lower temperatures freeze water.  The water becomes frozen. We call such water frozen water, or ice.

Answer (score 1):

"Grey" is a simple straightforward adjective. "To grey" and "to grey out" are verbs formed from that word. "Greyed" or "greyed out" are the participle forms of those 2 verbs. But, as Weather Vane says, in your sentence the participle "greyed out" performs the function of an adjective (not a verb).

So the sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to give more information about something, you can use an adjective to describe it in more detail. e.g.: a *light brown* suit, a *greenish* glass, a *greyed out* vision.